# is it possible to publish parts of your solution with github actions? c#

Tags: c#, azure-functions, github-actions

At this moment i have a solution with 1 api, 6 functions and 1 library.
when manually publishing this with visual studio there are no problems.
now i want to be able to do this with github... i have 1 branch, and i want to be able to deploy the functions seperatly on changes... so for example i know there is a change and then i have the possibility to choose what action i want to run... "publish api", "publish function 1" etc... (i check manually where the change is ofc) but is it possible? or will it always publish the entire solution to azure?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is create a pipeline and then inside the pipeline deploy the api and function separately.

You can do this with azure pipeline or github action.

After the separate deployment you can use triggers to deploy them the way you want.

Refer the following [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-deployment-technologies) on deployment technologies in functions.

Refer the following [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/github/github-actions) on Github action.

Refer the following [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/triggers?view=azure-devops) on pipeline triggers.